# Where did odata sdk code sample go?

Tags: odata

I am trying achieve the same thing asked by this question, [Routing in WCF data services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220099/routing-in-wcf-data-services)

It seems like the code sample linked in the answer is no longer valid, but I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.  Anyone know where I can download the sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code links are now all verified functional at http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/.